# Separating bibitems according to author

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex. Is there a way to have 3 lists of bibliographies which contain the following:

- the first contains some papers I have written (`type=article`)
- the second contains preprints I have written (`type=unpublished`)
- the third contains other papers that are cited (i.e., not written by myself).

I manage to do the first two by using

```
\printbibliography[title={Published papers},type=article,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title={Preprints},type=unpublished,heading=subbibliography]
```

but I don't know how to separate the papers by other authors from these two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution requiring some manual work (you have to define what are your papers).

You create a category for your papers

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{mine}
```

and you populate it with

```
\addtocategory{mine}{
  mypaper1,
  mypaper2,
  ...
}
```

Then you use:

```
\printbibliography[title={Published papers},
   type=article, heading=subbibliography, category=mine]
```

to print your published articles

```
\printbibliography[title={Preprints},
   type=unpublished, heading=subbibliography, category=mine]
```

for your unpublished papers, and

```
\printbibliography[notcategory=mine]
```

for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You also can add the fields:

```
keywords={mypapers}, keywords={mypreprints}
```

to your papers and preprints in the `.bib` file.

Then

```
\printbibliography[title={Published papers}, keyword=mypapers, heading=subbibliography]

\printbibliography[title={Preprints}, keyword=mypreprints, heading=subbibliography]

\printbibliography[title={References}, notkeyword=mypreprints, notkeyword=mypapers, heading=subbibliography]
```